# Leaflet MapBox addlayer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I'm newbie in coding and I'm trying to modify some downloaded GitHub code to make customized application and display my data.

AddLayer function is making me desperate.
I'm trying to add data from MapBox account by changing  the part of code with my Mapbox username and project id:

```
 L.mapbox.tileLayer('myMBid.n7i50n7g'), 
      L.mapbox.gridLayer('myMBid.n7i50n7g'),
```

Please share your coding knowledge with me and teach me how can I modify code to be able to load data from MapBox?

Or how can I, inside this coding, insert option to load geojson or topojson files from application folder?

Full Code:

```
<pre>
var map = L.map('map',{maxZoom:17,minZoom:1}).setView([45.2701486, 18.5586462], 13);

L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.myMBpublickey';

var baseLayer = new L.mapbox.tileLayer('myMBid.hl6099hm').addTo(map);

// ADD LAYER CONTROLLER
var ui = document.getElementById('layerControls');

//ADD FIRST LAYER
addLayer(
  L.mapbox.tileLayer('myMBid.j2rlctfi'), 
  L.mapbox.gridLayer('myMBid.j2rlctfi'), 
  'Administrativne granice', 
  1
);

//ADD SECOND LAYER
addLayer(
  L.mapbox.tileLayer('myMBid.n7i50n7g'), 
  L.mapbox.gridLayer('myMBid.n7i50n7g'), 
  'Soil Types', 
  3
);

function addLayer(layer, gridlayer, name, zIndex) {
  layer.setZIndex(zIndex);
  var gridControl = L.mapbox.gridControl(gridlayer, {position: 'bottomleft'}).addTo(map);
  // Create a simple layer switcher that toggles layers on
  // and off.
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = '#';
  link.className = 'btn btn-primary btn-sm';
  link.type = 'button';
  link.innerHTML = name;
  link.onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (map.hasLayer(layer)) {
      map.removeLayer(layer);
      map.removeControl(gridControl);
      this.className = 'btn btn-primary btn-sm';
    } else {
      map.addLayer(layer);
      map.addLayer(gridlayer);
      map.addControl(gridControl);
      this.className = 'active btn btn-primary btn-sm';
    }
  };
  ui.appendChild(link);
};

// ADD THE REFERENCE OVERLAY
var topPane = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-top-pane', map.getPanes().mapPane);
var topLayer = new L.mapbox.tileLayer('landplanner.hl60jemk', {
  maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);
topPane.appendChild(topLayer.getContainer());
topLayer.setZIndex(7);
</pre>
```

Comment: Interesting how Mapbox data (i.e. maxmeles.Spb-Moscow) from this example is working when I include them in my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414138/mapbox-js-exclusive-layer-switcher-toggle

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using the following:

```
L.mapbox.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/YOUR_MAP_ID/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN')
```

All you have to do is replace **YOUR_MAP_ID** and **YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN** in the above snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to check if my MapBox data is ok and I tested the code in Plunker:

```
    L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZm5ldmlzdGljIiwiYSI6IkZyYy03U28ifQ.tI5Od3maJWFflOMcit5vDg';

var map = L.mapbox.map('mapbox', 'fnevistic.n7o8oi8c', {
  'center': [45.25, 18.55],
  'zoom': 12
});
```

Everything is working fine. Map is displayed, pop-up is working.
Now I'm trying to find the way to implement that code inside existing one:

```
//ADD FIRST LAYER
addLayer(
  L.mapbox.tileLayer('myMBid.j2rlctfi'), 
  L.mapbox.gridLayer('myMBid.j2rlctfi'), 
  'Administrativne granice', 
  1
);
```

I've made code corrections according to Evil Genius instructions:

```
//ADD FIRST LAYER
addLayer(
  L.mapbox.tileLayer(''https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/fnevistic.n7o8oi8c/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZm5ldmlzdGljIiwiYSI6IkZyYy03U28ifQ.tI5Od3maJWFflOMcit5vDg'), 
  L.mapbox.gridLayer(''https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/fnevistic.n7o8oi8c/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZm5ldmlzdGljIiwiYSI6IkZyYy03U28ifQ.tI5Od3maJWFflOMcit5vDg'), 
  'Administrativne granice', 
  1
);
```

When I run the application I'm getting these errors:

*

> GET
>   https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/fnevistic.n7o8oi8c/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.pn…token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZm5ldmlzdGljIiwiYSI6IkZyYy03U28ifQ.tI5Od3maJWFflOMcit5vDg
>   404 (Not Found)
>   i @ mapbox.js:1e.exports @
>   mapbox.js:6e.exports._loadTileJSON @
>   mapbox.js:6L.TileLayer.extend.initialize @ mapbox.js:6s.Class.extend.e
>   @ mapbox.js:1e.exports @ mapbox.js:7(anonymous function) @
>   physicalLayers.js:15 mapbox.js:7

could not load TileJSON at

> https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/fnevistic.n7o8oi8c/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZm5ldmlzdGljIiwiYSI6IkZyYy03U28ifQ.tI5Od3maJWFflOMcit5vDg
>   e.exports.log
>   @ mapbox.js:7(anonymous function) @ mapbox.js:6s.Util.bind @
>   mapbox.js:1s @ mapbox.js:6o @ mapbox.js:1

*

Comment: `L.mapbox.tileLayer(''https://{s}`: Are there two " ' " on purpose in front of 'HTTPS'? Please incorporate edits and other changes into your question and not as an answer.

Comment: Still not working. Getting this error in console: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE"